# Mysql: ¿Es posible invocar un alias en 1 misma consulta para obtener otro dato?

Tags: mysql, self

Buenas tardes estimados,

Verán no soy experto y quería saber si lo que estoy intentando hacer es posible. Imaginemos que tenemos sólo 1 tabla en ese tabla tenemos los siguientes datos

Tabla_prueba

Nombre
Fecha

Ejemplo: Nombre: Luis, Fecha: 2020-03-18

Lo primero que quiero hacer es un substring a la fecha para obtener el Mes

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT Nombre, SUBSTRING(Fecha, 6,2) AS MesDosDigitos FROM Tabla_prueba;
```

El resultado sería:

|Nombre | MesDosDigitos |

|Luis  |      02       |

Pero yo quiero en 1 misma consulta hacer uso de ese alias "MesDosDigitos" para convertirlos
meses que ya tengo a 2 dígitos en meses con nombre con un case

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT CASE MesDosDigitos

WHEN MesDosDigitos = 05 THEN 'Mayo'

WHEN MesDosDigitos = 04 THEN 'Abril'

WHEN MesDosDigitos = 03 THEN 'Marzo'

END;
```

Lo que se me ocurre es usar un INNER JOIN similar a los siguiente:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*  FROM

(SELECT Nombre, SUBSTRING(Fecha, 6,2) AS MesDosDigitos FROM Tabla_prueba) AS A 

INNER JOIN

(SELECT CASE MesDosDigitos 

WHEN MesDosDigitos = 05 THEN 'Mayo'

WHEN MesDosDigitos = 04 THEN 'Abril'

WHEN MesDosDigitos = 03 THEN 'Marzo'

END) AS B

ON A.Mes = B.Mes
```

Obviamente la anterior consulta no me corre :'(

El resultado que busco es éste

|Nombre | MesDosDigitos | MesconNombre |

| Luis   |     03        |   Marzo     |

Aiuda PLEASE!!

Comment: No necesitas hacer tanto. Si antes haces `SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';`, lo puedes conseguir mas fácil con `SELECT date_format(Fecha,'%d %M')`

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas la columna del alias para obtener el substring, sino que la extracción del substring puede ser directamente el valor a evaluar, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    SUBSTRING(Fecha, 6,2) As MesDosDigitos,
    CASE SUBSTRING(Fecha, 6,2)
        WHEN 01 THEN 'Enero'
        WHEN 02 THEN 'Enero'
        WHEN 03 THEN 'Marzo'
        WHEN 04 THEN 'Abril'
        WHEN 05 THEN 'Mayo'
        WHEN 06 THEN 'Junio'
        WHEN 07 THEN 'Julio'
        WHEN 08 THEN 'Agosto'
        WHEN 09 THEN 'Septiembre'
        WHEN 10 THEN 'Octubre'
        WHEN 11 THEN 'Noviembre'
        WHEN 12 THEN 'Diciembte'
    END AS MesConNombre
FROM Tabla_prueba;
```

Si tu columna `Fecha` es del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME`  sería aún mucho más simple.

Puedes cambiar el lenguaje con [`lc_time_names`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lc_time_names) y extraer el dígito y nombre del mes del siguiente modo:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
SELECT 
    LPAD(MONTH(Fecha), 2, '0') AS MesDosDigitos,
    MONTHNAME(Fecha) AS MesConNombre
FROM Tabla_prueba;
```

O, puedes valerte también de `DATE_FORMAT` combinado con `lc_time_names` del siguiente modo:

```
SET lc_time_names = 'es_ES';
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(Fecha, '%d') AS MesDosDigitos,
    DATE_FORMAT(Fecha, '%M') AS MesConNombre
FROM Tabla_prueba;
```

Si te interesa mostrar una sola columna con ambos valores también puedes hacerlo, como te indica @Sal en su comentario.

Comment: Eres el mejor! Muchas gracias ImI :D ImI